# SSL keytool error: java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match. while importing intermmediate certificate

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, keytool

Generated CSR and Keystore.

```
keytool -genkey -alias posbo -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks -keysize 1024

keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -keysize 1024 -alias posbo -file certreq.csr -keystore keystore.jks -storepass changeit
```

Generated Root, Intermmediate and Server Certificate....

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out root-ca.key 1024 

openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key root-ca.key -out root-ca.crt -config openssl.cfg


openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca-int.key 1024 

openssl req -new -days 365 -key ca-int.key -out ca-int.csr -config openssl.cfg

openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in ca-int.csr -CA root-ca.crt -CAkey root-ca.key -set_serial 01 -out ca-int.crt 



openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in certreq.csr -CA root-ca.crt -CAkey root-ca.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt.
```

Now Importing root , intermmediate and server crt into keystore.jks

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias rootca -file root-ca.crt -keystore keystore.jks
Success.


keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias intercom -file ca-int.crt -keystore keystore.jks.
keytool error: java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match
```

Any suggestion or reason for above error.

Answer (score 0):

Your commands work for me.

What versions of keytool and openssl are you using?  Have you tried this on another server/version/OS?  What is in your openssl.cfg file?

One thing I noticed that doesn't look correct is in your last openssl command, you are signing the end certificate with the root instead of the intermediate (int-ca.key).  Try signing with that instead and then import it.  That shouldn't be causing this problem, but if you have an intermediate CA, I'm guessing you want to use it to sign the end certificate instead of the root.  Otherwise, the intermediate doesn't really have any value.